# Using key option to package that uses string cases

Tags: xstring, package-options, kvoptions

What's wrong with the following package and source file? I get an error at line 14, after `[Other]`, of `mypackage.sty`, and a "Missing \begin{document}" error resulting.

The source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[what=this]{mypackage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The package `mypackage.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{xstring}

\DeclareStringOption{what}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\IfStrEqCase{what}{%
    {this}{\dothis}%
    {that}{\dothat}%
    }%
    [Other]%

\newcommand{\dothis}{The magic word is ``this''}
\newcommand{\dothat}{The magic word is ``that''}

\endinput
```

I strongly suspect there's some simple syntactical error that I can't find. Or else there's something basic that I'm not understanding about either `kvoptions` or `xstring`

I think my syntax for `\IfStrEqCase` is OK, because the docs from `texdoc xstring` give the form:

```
\IfStrEqCase⟨[*]⟩{⟨string⟩}{% 
    {⟨string1⟩}{⟨code1⟩}% 
    {⟨string2 ⟩}{⟨code2 ⟩}%
    etc...
    {⟨stringN ⟩}{⟨codeN ⟩}}[⟨other cases code⟩]
```

**My actual purpose**

My actual purpose of `kvoptions` and `xstring` is for a complex document where:

- In one custom package read in as part of the preamble, I set a value for a key for one of several possible document text/math font choices. And in that same package, depending on that value, give the requisite commands to use that text/math font combination. (E.g., with `cm` as the font choice, which will be a default, the requisite command will simply be `\usepackage{amsfonts}`; with `lucida` as the font choice, instead, the requisite commands will be `\usepackage[lucidasmallscale]{lucidabr}` and `\linespread{1.04}`.)
- A second custom package read in as part of the preamble gives a large set of math command definitions, some of which depend on the math font being used. So this second package will take that key value as option, use it, inside a `\IfStrEqCase` expression, to alter the commands as needed. For example, for the `cm` choice, I specify `\newcommand{\nsubset}{\not\subset}` and `\newcommand{\tendsto}{\rightarrow}`; whereas for the `lucida` choice, since `\nsubset` is already defined, I don't need to define it, but I use `tikz` to create, as the definition for `\tendsto`, an arrow that better harmonizes with arrows appearing in `tikz-cd` diagrams.

The points of this seemingly complicated setup are:

1. To allow the font choice to be made by editing a single line in the first package, rather than having to comment and uncomment large blocks of text in source files.
2. To allow my second package, with all its math definitions, to be used not just in this particular document, but in any document that may need my specialized math definitions.

Comment: I admit to not being familiar with either `kvoptions` or `xstring`, but I interpret `\IfStrEqCase` as being a choice.  If `[Other]` is supposed to be within its scope, it should probably be inside the closing brace, but it isn't, and it's being recognized as "text input", so is processed immediately.  That's not legit, since text can be accepted only after `\begin{document}`, hence the cause of the error message.  Better check the documentation for the syntax of `\IfStrEqCase`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I think te `\IfStrEqCase` syntax *is* OK, with the  `[Other]` seemingly dangling at its end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem, which causes the error is that you are executing the `\IfStrEqCase` statement inside the package code to produce typeset output, however you can't do that before `\begin{document}`. I wrapped the test in a definition `\mytest` which can be used inside the document.

The other problem is that you are comparing `what` with `this` or `that`, which will never match and will go to the `other` branch. When you set up a key-value option `<name>` with `kvoptions`, the value passed to the option `<name>` will be stored in `\<prefix>@<name>`. The `<prefix>` can be changed, but the default is the package name, so `mypackage`, and `<name>` is `what` here, so instead of testing `what` you should test `\mypackage@what`. Changing that, the code prints `The magic word is “this”`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\DeclareStringOption{what}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\def\mytest{%
  \IfStrEqCase{\mypackage@what}{%
      {this}{\dothis}%
      {that}{\dothat}%
      }%
      [Other]%
  }
\newcommand{\dothis}{The magic word is ``this''}
\newcommand{\dothat}{The magic word is ``that''}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[what=this]{mypackage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\mytest

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

For this case in particular you could drop `xstring` and test if a macro `\do<what>` exists. If it does, use it, otherwise take the appropriate action. This definition for `\mytest` would produce the same output as the one with `xstring`:

```latex
\def\mytest{%
  \@ifundefined{do\mypackage@what}%
    {Other}%
    {\@nameuse{do\mypackage@what}}%
  }
```

Comment: The docs (`texdoc xstring`) are quite misleading in this, in that they give, on page 6, examples such as  `\IfStrEqCase{c}{{a}{AA}{b}{BB}{c}{CC}}[other]` but without any discussion that I see of using `\IfStrEqCase`, etc., in packages.

Comment: @murray Well, they don't, but I would't say it's misleading. It is well known that you can't write text before the `\begin{document}` and that packages can _only_ be loaded before `\begin{document}`, so it's sort of implied. What is your actual use case? Do you really want to make your package write something at load time?

Comment: What is the purpose, and what the necessity, of using `\mypackage@what` rather than just plain `what` as the first argument to `\IfStrEqCase`? Is it possible because the command `\DeclareStringOption{what}`in effect automatically creates `\mypackage@what`? And just why must one use a command as that argument, which examples in the docs for `xstring` don't show at all. It cannot be simply because, within a package, one cannot use a raw string (after all, `\RequirePackage{what}` does use a raw string). I'm trying to understand how all this works, and not just follow your correction.

Comment: @murray The second paragraph in my answer explains why `\mypackage@what` instead of `what`. For TeX `what` is just the text string "what" with no special meaning. If you compare `what` with `this` it will _always_ result false. When you do `\DeclareStringOption{what}` a macro called `\mypackage@what` is created and it contains the value passed to the option `what` (in the example, `this`). Then, when you compare `\mypackage@what` (which contains `this`) with `this` you get true. If you want examples with commands you need to go further in the manual (Section 4 Advanced macros for programming).

Comment: @murray `\RequirePackage{what}` is something else entirely. With this instruction you are telling LaTeX to search for a file named `what.sty`, then `what` needs to be a bunch of characters which represent a file name. If you were to put `\RequirePackage{\mypackage@what}` it would (if you used `what=this`) try to load a package called `this.sty` because `\mypackage@what` expands to `this`.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo in my *comment*: I meant to say "`\DeclareStringOption{what}`". Can you answer my question given that type correction?

Comment: Section 4, "Advanced macros for programming", in the docs for `xstring` didn't help me at all, as they seemed to concern additional commands defined in the package and involved lower-level things, with TeX, not LaTeX, usages.

Comment: @murray As I said, internally `\DeclareStringOption{what}` defines a command called `\mypackage@what` which will expand to the value given to the actual option `what`. Doing `\DeclareStringOption{what}` and then `\usepackage[what=this]{mypackage}` is the same as doing `\def\mypackage@what{this}`, but with a user interface. It's explained in the second paragraph of my answer and in section **2.2.1 `\DeclareStringOption`** of the `kvoptions` manual.

Comment: @murray Usually package writing is done by users with a little experience on TeX macro expansion model, so package authors don't bother explaining that to end users (which I have to agree that sometimes makes a barrier for the newcomer which wants to learn it: I've been there, and it's not easy). Perhaps section 3 of the `xstring` manual can give you a light on how it expands its arguments, but again, you need to be a little familiar with the concept of expansion and other low-level TeX concepts.